# Calculate sample size (n) for 2 populations

Tags: proportion, sample

We have a pre-study that gives us the amount of people voting for the left wing in one region (0,25%) with N = 123490 and (0,22%) N = 150578.

We need to know how large sample sizes we need in order to, with 90% power and significance level 0,1% "show" the difference between the two regions that seems to be (0,03) according to the pre-study. Also, the sample sizes needs to be proportional against the number of people in each region so $n_2$ should be 1,219 times larger than $n_1$.

We suspect that we need to use this formula:

$$z = \frac{(\hat p_1 - \hat p_2) - (p_1 - p_2)}{\sqrt{\bar p \bar q \left( \frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2} \right)}}. $$

How would you calculate the sample size for each region?